# How to read a list of variable names and substitute them in a function in R?

Tags: r, variables, substitution

I would like to write a script that reads a list of variable names. These variable names are some of the column headers in a data.frame. Then I want to do a for-loop to execute various operations on the specified variables in the data.frame and print them in accordingly named files, but I can't figure out how to do the necessary variable substitution. The data.frame has 1260 columns and 2600 rows. Not all columns are continuous variables, some are factors, descriptors, etc., so I use the varlist to pick which columns I want to analyze.

I found basically the same question in https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/228752.html, but the author's suggestions don't work for me.

```
#Example script scaled down for simplicity
Dataset <- iris
varlist <- data.frame("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")
for (i in 1:length(varlist)){
    model <- lm(SOMETHINGHERE_i ~ Petal.Width, data = Dataset)
    printing <- data.frame(SOMETHINGHERE_i = model$coefficients['Petal.Width'])
    write.csv(printing,paste0("C://Users/Me/Desktop/",SOMETHINGHERE_i,"/",SOMETHINGHERE_i,"PetalWidthSlope.csv"))
}
```

The page I linked above says that I should put `varlist[i]` and it works for the saving part, but the model gives error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in:
> "    model <- lm(varlist[i] ~ Petal.Width, data = Dataset)
> printing <- data.frame(varlist[i] ="

It also suggests using `sapply(Dataset[varlist], function)`, but I don't know how to apply it to `lm`, but regardless, if I try with `sapply(Dataset[varlist], mean), it prints:

> Error in `[.default`(Dataset, varlist) : invalid subscript type 'list'

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `as.formula` to convert text to valid R formulas. (But as you are discovering you cannot use R formulas as macros.) I also used just the `varlist` items as the loop variables rather than sequential integers.

```
Dataset <- iris
varlist <- data.frame("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")
for (i in varlist ){ form <- as.formula( paste( i, "~ Petal.Width"))
     model <- lm(form, data = Dataset)
     printing <- data.frame(i = model$coefficients['Petal.Width'])
     write.csv(printing,paste0("~/Desktop/",i,"PetalWidthSlope.csv"))
    }
```

I now have 3 more files on my Desktop:

[image]